# Stomp client on subscribe create new array javascripts

Tags: javascript, arrays, stomp

I am using javascript Stomp client to subscribe when server sent the message.

#### The need

I need to create a new array of subscribed messages. Each message has different id. If the id exists then nothing will be pushed, but if the array does not exist then new object will be pushed to the empty array.

This is What I have tried

CODE:

```
var recivedData = []
    connect()
   function connect() {
        var socket = new SockJS('/info-app');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {

            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);

            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/info', function (msg) {

                    var parsedData = JSON.parse(msg.body)


                    if(!(recivedData.length)){
                        recivedData.push(parsedData)
                        console.log(recivedData)
                    } 

                    if(recivedData.length){
                        if(recivedData.find(e => e.id === parsedData.id)){
                            console.log(" there")
                            console.log(recivedData)
                        }
                        if(recivedData.find(e => e.id !== parsedData.id)){
                            console.log("not there")
                            recivedData.push(parsedData)
                            console.log(recivedData)
                        }
                    } 

                console.log(recivedData)

            });

        });
    }
```

#### The Problem

whenever new id enters it is pushing to the array, but if the same id enters again it is also pushing.

How can I solve that? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to execute `if(recivedData.length){` block after you already pushed data into first empty array. Use `else` part of the `if` statement:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/topic/info', function(msg) {

  var parsedData = JSON.parse(msg.body)

  if (!recivedData.length) {
    recivedData.push(parsedData)
    console.log(recivedData)
  } else {
    if (recivedData.some(e => e.id === parsedData.id)) {
      console.log(" there")
      console.log(recivedData)
    } else {
      console.log("not there")
      recivedData.push(parsedData)
      console.log(recivedData)
    }
  }

  console.log(recivedData)
});
```